# Full table row select an Top up popup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following javascript to do a full table row select wich works very well.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{

  $('#link-table td:first-child').hide();

  $('#link-table tr').hover(function ()
  {
    $(this).toggleClass('Highlight');
  });


  $('#link-table tr').click(function ()
  {
    location.href = $(this).find('td a').attr('href');
  });
});
```

Now i want to open the link in the selected row in [Top up Popop](http://gettopup.com/), but adjusting the `href` does not work.

I think, I have to adjust something in `location.href = $(this).find('td a').attr('href');` but I do not know how to do this.

Comment: try this location.href = $(this).find('td > a').attr('href');

Comment: location.href = $(this).find('td > a').attr('href'); That does not make any change, it still opens in a new page, not a popup.

Answer (score 0):

this code will solve your problem

```
$(this).find('td a').click();
```

Comment: This will fire click event on your anchor tag on which you already applied "Top ip popup"

Comment: replace     location.href = $(this).find('td a').attr('href'); with $(this).find('td a').click();